# Вывести на экран даты и время входа пользователя Гость за сентябрь 2016 года

Tags: логирование, sed

Вывести на экран даты и время входа пользователя Гость за сентябрь 2016 года.

Пример лога:

Аудит успеха    27.09.2016 15:19:30 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing 4648    Вход в систему  "Выполнена попытка входа в систему с явным указанием учетных данных.

Субъект:
ИД безопасности:        система
Имя учетной записи:     MY-COMP$
Домен учетной записи:   WORKGROUP
Код входа:              0x3e7
GUID входа: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Были использованы учетные данные следующей учетной записи:
Имя учетной записи:     Гость

Ответом будут строки:

27.09.2016 15:20:12
27.09.2016 15:19:30
27.09.2016 13:33:08
27.09.2016 13:33:08
26.09.2016 14:57:29
22.09.2016 16:46:15
22.09.2016 16:43:08
22.09.2016 15:23:33
15.09.2016 15:07:36
15.09.2016 15:07:36
13.09.2016 15:38:54
13.09.2016 15:38:54
01.09.2016 7:04:23

Подсказка:  нужно сначала научиться искать строки, начинающейся с  «Аудит успеха» и содержащие внутри себя дату сентября 2016. Далее из этой строки нужно удалить всё кроме даты и времени, и положить получившуюся  строчку в область удержания.  Выводить данные из области удержания нужно, только если вход был осуществлен от имени пользователя Гость

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вывести с помощью  sed на экран даты и время входа пользователя  за 09. 2016 года из логов log.txt.    Ответом будет: 27.09.2016 15:20:12, 27.09.2016 15:19:30....